# How to assign numeric multiplier to a variable in or-tools (C++)

Tags: c++, or-tools

```
std::vector<const MPVariable *> P(mP);
for (int a = 1; a <= mP; a++)
    P[a - 1] = solver->MakeBoolVar("P"+std::to_string(a));

for (int a = 1; a <= mP; a++)
{
    LinearExpr eq;
    for (int b = 1; b <= T; b++)
    {
      ; //eq += ... ;
    }
    eq -=  T * P[a - 1]; // error; however, eq -=  P[a - 1] is okay.
    solver->MakeRowConstraint(eq <= 0.0);
}
```

`eq -=  T * P[a - 1]` gives error. However, `eq -=  P[a - 1]` is okay. `T` is an `int`.

Error msg:

```
 invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<const operations_research::MPVariable*>, const operations_research::MPVariable*>::value_type’ {aka ‘const operations_research::MPVariable*’} to binary ‘operator*’
```

How to assign a numeric multiplier (`T`) to the variable (`P[a - 1]`)?

Additionally, how to print the LP model that was generated, so that I can debug it?

Comment: This will give `no match for ‘operator*’ (operand types are ‘int’ and ‘const operations_research::MPVariable’)`

Comment: you can try [SetCoefficient](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/cpp)

Comment: @Dr.PB, I tried, `MPConstraint* const ct = solver->MakeRowConstraint(eq <= 0.0);` and then `ct->SetCoefficient(P[p - 1], T);`. But not sure about the right/better way.

Comment: How to print the LP model that was generated, so that I can debug it?

Comment: Don't put question details in the comments: instead edit the question.

Comment: I've never used OR-tools, but a quick google tells me the `int T` (bad variable name) needs to be converted to an `IntVar`.

Comment: That does not work. Thank you for your reply though. Only `SetCoefficient` is working. However, yet to verify.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I had originally erroneously showed the code for the CP-SAT Solver, not the MIP solver, corrected here.

In the documentation at https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/linear_solver/linear_expr.h#L174 I can see an overloading of the simple arithmetic operators for `LinearExpr` as follows:

```
LinearExpr operator+(LinearExpr lhs, const LinearExpr& rhs);
LinearExpr operator-(LinearExpr lhs, const LinearExpr& rhs);
LinearExpr operator*(LinearExpr lhs, double rhs);
LinearExpr operator/(LinearExpr lhs, double rhs);
LinearExpr operator*(double lhs, LinearExpr rhs);
```

There is no overloading for multiplication with `int`, you'll need to use a double for the factor instead of an `int` like this:

```
double doubleT = double(T);
eq -= doubleT * P[a - 1];
```

Comment: That does not work. Thank you for your reply though. Only `SetCoefficient` is working. However, yet to verify.